# Read string between certain character and after character

Tags: c#

I want users to create their own POS print file while following some rules. So I have small Parameters.txt file which can be modified by users. Inside that file there are some strings like this:

```
<CENTER><BOLD>My Header Text 
Just some random no parameters input
from user
Date:<NOWDATE> Time:<NOWTIME>
```

I want to read everything between `<>` as `string1`, and everything that is not inside `<>` as separated `string2`.

So `<NOWDATE>` would be parameter that is recognized by code and inserts Date instead of that string, but `Date:` would be just some text entered by user which would just be passed to POS printer as string.

Also, users can do something like this:

```
<CENTER><BOLD>Today<NOWDATE>:<NOWTIME>
```

So instead of `<CENTER>` there would be some ESC/POS command inserted, same in place of `<BOLD>`, but `Today` would be just passed as normal string without anything changed.
It can be all in one big string, but i need a way to distinguish strings inside `<>` and outside of `<>`

I know how to read string inside `<>`, currently I am playing with this

```cs
private static string FindStringInBetween(string Text, string FirstString, string LastString)
{
    string STRFirst = FirstString;
    string STRLast = LastString;
    string FinalString;

    int Pos1 = Text.IndexOf(FirstString) + FirstString.Length;
    int Pos2 = Text.IndexOf(LastString);

    FinalString = Text.Substring(Pos1, Pos2 - Pos1);

    return FinalString;
}
```

But this will only get string inside first `<>`, and ignore everything else.
Can you recommend best way of achieving this?

Comment: Can you show what would be your desired result and output for your first and second examples?

Comment: X-Y. You obviously want to implement some sort of markup-rendering. If it actually is as easy as [replacing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=netframework-4.8#System_String_Replace_System_String_System_String_) some substrings in each line, why don't you just do so?

Comment: Could you be more specific on expected output. Could you pls share what would be output for a specific example, let us say, what would be output for `<CENTER><BOLD>Today<NOWDATE>:<NOWTIME>`

Comment: @Salah Akbari string1 would be parameters passed to POS printer, for example BOLD is passed as (char)(0x1D) + (char)(0x21). But string2 is passed just as string. So if string reads <BOLD> it will pass esc code to printer, if it reads something without <> then it will pass what it reads.

Comment: @Anu Wisan for `<CENTER><BOLD>Today<NOWDATE>:<NOWTIME> To printer would be passed '(char)(0x1B)+(char)(0x61)+(char)(0x1)+(char)(0x1D) + "Today:2020-04-02:09:20'`  But i just need tto know if string is inside <> or outside and what is the string.

Comment: @Fildor thank you. I made this more complex than it really is or needed to be. Replacing was simplest and fastest way.

Answer (score 0):

At the end i used combination of String.Replace

```
 TempString = TempString.Replace("<CENTER>", Center);
```

and spliting string when finding that it contain certain combination of characters.

```
if (TempString.Contains("<="))
{
   var _parametar = "<=ReceiptNumber>"; 

   string s = TempString;
   int start = s.IndexOf("<=") + 2;
   int end = s.IndexOf(">", start);
   string _splitResult = s.Substring(start, end - start);

}
```